# Re-entering the UK have short-term student child unaccompanied visa

Tags: uk, study, russian-citizens

Can I re-enter the UK having this type of Visa (valid until January 1, 2019) for a 12-day tour?

Comment: Have you already completed the study course for which the visa was originally granted? To be eligible for a short term study visa you must have been offered a place on a course in the UK at an accepted place of study https://www.gov.uk/study-visit-visa/eligibility If you want to re-enter on the same visa you’ll need to be able to show Immigration proof of one or more consecutive or concurrent programme(s) of study that will be completed within the six month validity period of the short-term study visa https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-part-3-students

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Yes, I have already completed the course

Answer (score 2):

Your course is over therefore the premise for your Short Term Study visa is no longer valid. Seeking to enter the UK on a short term study visa where the course is finished gives Immigration the right (but not the obligation) to remove you under Paragraph 320 of the rules. https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-part-9-grounds-for-refusal
(1) the fact that entry is being sought for a purpose not covered by these Rules.

If you want to enter the UK as a tourist you’ll need to apply for a Standard Visitor visa.